# Cannot access a shared printer on a network

Tags: windows, networking, troubleshooting, network-printer

I can't access a shared printer on a network. I'm using a Windows 7 PC.

The problem is when I type an IP on the start logo search bar that has a shared printer, "\\172.16.0.254" a window will appear which says:

Windows cannot access \\172.16.0.254

Error code: 0x80070035 The network path was not found.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Can you ping that IP?

Comment: yes it is up, i can ping it

Answer (score 0):

Windows HomeGroups can automatically configure printer sharing, permission, etc. among Windows 7 or 8 computers.

If you're not joined to a local HomeGroup, my bet is it's a firewall issue...

johnwill at techsupportforum.com says it well: "Turn off any firewalls for debugging. If the firewall is the problem, you'll have to configure it to allow access to "trusted zone" addresses. Note that some firewalls must be completely uninstalled to stop them from affecting your networking.

PING each computer by IP address, and if successful, PING by name. You can obtain the IP address of a computer by opening a command prompt (DOS window) and typing IPCONFIG. This should work for any Windows version. A failure here needs to be corrected before you go any farther.

Check your Services are Started on all PCs: Workstation, DHCP Client, DNS Client, Server, TCP/IP Netbios helper, Computer Browser.

All computers should be in the same workgroup for computer browsing to function properly. File & Print Sharing has to be enabled on any computer you wish to share files or printers from. You also need to actually share the resource in question from My Computer, right click on the drive/printer/folder, and select sharing.

If you encounter difficulties accessing computers that are visible in Network Neighborhood, make sure the computer being accessed has an account with the same name/password as the system connecting to it uses to login.

While the default NetBIOS setting is correct for normal network configurations, it's possible for it to be altered, and it costs nothing to make sure it's correct. NETBIOS over TCP/IP must be enabled for normal network browsing."

Comment: My file and printing is enables. I did all what you said. I also disabled the firewall. I cannot also access any computer in the network. It says I have no permission.

Comment: Can you ping the other computer successfully? If the other computer is running Windows 7 or 8 Home editions, the easiest thing to do is setup a Homegroup. Otherwise, you have to setup accounts on both computers with the same username and password (it cannot be blank) and grant permissions in the share configuration where the printer is attached.